# A guide or tool for inserting bootstrap in underscores theme?

Tags: theme-development

I am looking for a guide or tool for inserting [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) in to [underscores](https://github.com/automattic/_s) theme.
Booststrap is a CSS framework and Underscores theme is starter theme with ultra-minimal CSS.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to not use twitter bootstrap web 3.0 jargon? What do you mean by bootstrapping underscores? bootstrap and udnerscore are separate frameworks, it's not clear what you want

Comment: Booststrap is a CSS framework and Underscores theme is starter theme with ultra-minimal CSS. I edit question, i hope you like new version

Comment: If your question is what i think it is then it's purely a html/CSS question, not a WP question and so the bootstrap docs have your answer and this question is offtopic

Comment: That and underscores is a starter theme, not a theme of itself, you're supposed to modify it

Comment: A recent guide to this is available online. It's a little strangely worded, but you should be able to follow along anyway http://www.kungfunguyen.com/make-custom-wordpress-theme-bootstrap-3-underscores/

Comment: [Root.io](https://roots.io/) also have bootstrap included. Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a theme for this purpose. More details:
http://theme.firmasite.com/

Answer (score 0):

This plugin should do the trick: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/

It simply packages up boostrap's CSS and JS and inserts it in you theme (as long as the theme provides the right hooks to wordpress).

Comment: its just adding bootstrap to theme. Its not making theme to use bootstrap :<

Answer (score 0):

The following is a tutorial based on underscore: [WordPress Themes Templates Tutorial](http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/)

It can easily be modified to work with Bootstrap. The only thing you have to pay attention to is the new column classes in Bootstrap 3 and not adding the tutorials CSSS near the end.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of premade ones to start with; here are three:

**_tk**

https://github.com/Themekraft/_tk/

**alienship**

https://github.com/mindctrl/alienship

**Bootstraps**

https://github.com/tareq1988/_bootstraps

Answer (score 0):

I created a theme the goal of integrating Twitter's bootstrap into Automattic's underscores with the smallest possible changeset.
I'm keeping it up to date rather frequently with both _s and Bootstrap. Here is the link:
https://github.com/ptbello/_strap

At the time of writing, it's underscores' most popular fork
http://forked.yannick.io/Automattic/_s

Answer (score 0):

Other WordPress starter-themes that include Bootstrap:

https://github.com/SimonPadbury/bst